# What is the execute sequence of i++ in java

Tags: java

what is the execute sequence of following code?

```
 if (hash[s.charAt(right++)]-- >= 1)
```

In my understanding

```
 1. hash[s.charAt(right)] >= 1
 2. hash[s.charAt(right)]--
 3. right++;
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: please open eclipse, paste that snippet, run the code and share the results /your mind about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute sequence of `if (hash[s.charAt(right++)]-- >= 1)` is:

1. Read value of `hash` (a)
2. Read value of `s` (b)
3. Read value of `right` (c)
4. Increment value of `right`
5. Call `b.charAt(c)` (d)
6. Read value of `a[d]` (e)
7. Decrement value of `a[d]`
8. Read constant `1` (f)
9. Skip past `if` block if `e < f`.

If `hash`, `s`, and `right` are 3 local variables, the bytecode of the `if` statement is:

```
 1: aload_1
 2: aload_2
 3: iload_3
 4: iinc          3, 1
 5: invokevirtual #21                 // Method java/lang/String.charAt:(I)C
 6: dup2
    iaload
 7: dup_x2
    iconst_1
    isub
    iastore
 8: iconst_1
 9: if_icmplt     99
```

---

**UPDATE**

The *effect* is the same as-if you had written:

```
boolean cond = hash[s.charAt(right)];
hash[s.charAt(right)]--;
right++;
if (cond) {
```

Except that values are only read once, and `charAt()` call and index lookup only happens once.

Comment: thanks!  so is above code equal to                                                          `right++;                                                                                
if (hash[s.charAt(right)] >= 1);                                         
hash[s.charAt(right)]++;`    ?

Comment: No. The parameter value to `charAt()` is the value of `right` *before* the increment (steps 2, 3, and 5). The increment in step 4 happens after value of `right` has been retrieved.

Comment: Like this?     `        if (hash[s.charAt(right)] >= 1){
                hash[s.charAt(right)]--;
                right++;
            }`

Comment: No, the increment and decrement will happen whether condition is true or false.